# How to switch windows within PeekView window without mouse

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use use PeekDefinition keyboard shortcut a window is opened with a code preview on the left side and list of occurrences on the right side (typical PeekView).

Now the list on right has the focus. How to move it to the code preview without mouse so I could scroll it and edit it with my keyboard.

(I am using vim emulation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, on Windows with VSCode 1.37.1, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> moves from the right-hand pane of peek view (list of files) to the left-hand pane (peeked source code).

It doesn't seem to be an ordinary, customizable key binding though.  In my keyboard settings, several things are bound to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (depending on context), but none correspond to this behavior.  So I don't know where it comes from or if it can be changed.

Also, there seems to be no way to go back to the right-hand pane, other than by closing the peek view entirely with <kbd>Esc</kbd> and re-opening it again.